# No Video Found for url JMETER UBIK ULP Video Streaming Sampler

Tags: jmeter, mpeg-dash, ubikloadpack

I'm trying to Performance test an MPEG-DASH video streaming site using JMeter and the UBIK Loadpack.

I'm getting the error `No video found for url`, However, if I go to the URL in a browser the video plays

[image: 1]

Any Ideas what the problem is?

[1]:

Comment: Hello @big-ian, any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I got dragged off onto other projects and they got consultants in to do this project so I have no idea.  I do think the answer I got was pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the URL of a video stream.

You must enter the url of either:

- MPEG-Dash stream which ends with .mpd usually
- HLs which ends with m3u8
- MS Smooth

Please contact our support for further help.